# Can I get the old search menu back in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I don't like the new search thing in windows 8.1. How do I get it back?

I'm referring to the one where you would type your search, then a sidebar with the options `Programs`, `Settings` and `Files` would come up. It's changed/removed in windows 8.1.

Comment: You can disable the bing enchanted search but the old behavior was replaced

Answer (score 5):

If you are using search as an easy way to lauch programs then you might want to change the Windows button behavior. You can right click the **taskbar** → **properties** → **navigation** → **start screen**.

Select "**Show the apps view automatically when i go to Start**"
Deselect "**Search everywhere...**"

Hit ok. Now everytime you hit the start button or Winkey on your keyboard you will automatically go to the apps list and you can start typing to filter the list for the app you want. Now if you are looking for files and folders, then you will need the "Search everywhere" selected or just use the search on file explorer.

You can also remove bing integration from Search under **Settings** → **Change PC Settings** → **Search and Apps** → **Search**. Deselect "**Use bing to search online**".

Still, you will not have the old behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar is pretty much still there - there is no more program only search, but you can still search for files and settings by hitting on the downward pointing arrow on the subtitle under search.

[image]

Comment: I know but I don't like having the clickdown bar.

Comment: Lol We humans are so dang picky. I'm particular about stuff like that as well. Although in this case, it is what is is. There are some things in Windows 8 and 8.1 that we as a community have not figured out yet. They are still fairly new OSs and Microsoft has changed a lot in these two new distros. We still can't figure out how to get Aero back. Wait a few years and we will have all the answers lol.