# How do I revert back to windows 8 from 8.1?

Tags: windows-8

I [asked how to get the old search back](https://superuser.com/questions/662054/can-i-get-the-old-search-menu-back-in-windows-8-1) and the answer was that you can't.

Honestly, I haven't noticed any changes from 8 -> 8.1 besides a single tile has changed color (dunno why, the color doesn't even match the icon), and I really hate this new search thing. So how do I get 8 back?

Comment: You don't.  Unless you have a recovery disk for Windows 8.0 or an backup image of your system you don't.  The upgrade is one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it while on 8.1 preview using a Windows8 upgrade image i made before upgrading from Windows 7 to 8 but strange things happened like Skydrive not working anymore. It used to think I was still using Win8.1. Besides that, most of the OS was working fine until I upgraded to 8.1 final. I had several problems with permissions and policy errors. Metro apps won´t even start.

Said that, there's no official way to downgrade unless you´ve created a system image before upgrading.

Comment: I'm referring to the sidebar and how they removed the options for `Programs`, `Files` and `Settings`. That's really all I want back tbh.

Comment: i've edited my comment and replied on the right thread. You can still select files and settings from the drop down tho. The options is still there. Programs were moved exclusively to the apps list but if you search "everywhere" it will show programs, files, settings and everything else on your computer that matches the query.